# How do I deploy a Java AppEngine app using a Serverless VPC access connector with Google plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: google-plugin-eclipse

I created a Java AppEngine Standard application and managed the deployment through Google plugin for Eclipse. Then, I added a Serverless VPC access connector for a specific need. According to [Google documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/connecting-vpc), deployment must be done with the "beta" option:

> Note: To use Serverless VPC Access, make sure you use gcloud beta to deploy your service.

How do I manage this deployment with Google plugin for Eclipse?

I use Gradle

Comment: are you using maven/gradle to configure your build?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, using the gcloud beta feature is not supported in the Cloud Tools for Eclipse plugin (CT4E). (By the way, Google Plugin for Eclipse (GPE) is deprecated, but it is not clear if you are using CT4E or GPE.)

However, the latest App Engine Maven/Gradle plugins (Cloud SDK-based) support using the gcloud beta feature through the [`gclodeMode` parameter](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/app-maven-plugin/blob/master/USER_GUIDE.md#deploy) for deployment, so as a workaround, you could run the plugins on the command line (or invoke through IDE).